# Unknown PTR record in DNS; it’s not there in Cloudflare DNS Settings

Tags: domain-name-system, email, cloudflare, ptr-record, txt-record

(1.) There is an extra, unwanted, unexpected, unadded PTR record in my DNS settings, with value set to the Domain Name "mediati.net". You can see it here in MxToolbox Reverse Lookup:
[MxToolbox shows unwanted PTR TXT record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Jmd.jpg)

(2.) cPanel also notices and complains about the extra PTR record:
[cPanel also complains about the extra PTR record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gUOX.jpg)

(3.) Yet my DNS records in Cloudflare only have one PTR TXT record, the one I want. 
[DNS Records in Cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5g1S.jpg)

I haven't found anyone else with this same problem. Where could the PTR record to "mediati.net" be coming from !??

Paul

Comment: "PTR TXT" is wrongly named, a record type is either PTR or TXT not both, and you shouldn't have PTR record types in your forward zone, they are only useful in reverse zones to map IP addresses back to names, but this is seldom used (read: you live fine without PTR records). Also on asking questions: refrain to use images, put all data as text in your question directly.

Comment: Hi Patrick, sorry for the confusion, I'm referring to PTR records, which are types of TXT records, and indeed are useful for email setup. As indicated in my answer below, my ISP removed the unwanted PTR, so myy current one is working.

Comment: "PTR records, which are types of TXT records,".  No. `PTR` and `TXT` are both record types. One is not a type of another. See the full list of DNS record types at https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-4 if you do not believe me. You will see both `PTR` and `TXT` separately, they are completely independent. A `PTR` record type is a pointer, to associate an IP address (encoded as a specific name) to another name (in the reverse tree), and a `TXT` record associates a name with a list of strings, whose content is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why that PTR record existed, nor why it did not reflect what was in my Cloudflare DNS settings; however, my ISP was able to remove/change that PTR record for me.

That is some strange DNS record that I don't have control over.

Additional thoughts welcome here, but the current fix is that you can't fix it, you need your provider to fix it.